# Copy a file in Post Build of Eclipse/Truestudio

Tags: windows, eclipse, xcopy, post-build, truestudio

I was using arm-objcopy but it doesn't work with my .h file I need to copy to another project.

xcopy "../${project_loc}/src/folder/file.h" "....\OtherProject\folder\folder2\file.h" /Y

The error I get is "Invalid number of parameters". Earlier it was working enough to delete the existing file and ask "Is this File or Directory". /Y is supposed to quiet that according to xcopy docs, but then I find [Copy file(s) from one project to another using post build event...VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001822/copy-files-from-one-project-to-another-using-post-build-event-vs2010) which suggests otherwise? Either way it didn't let the copy happen quietly.

Project_loc from [What are the predefined variables in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30369044/what-are-the-predefined-variables-in-eclipse)

I would've thought this wouldn't take an hour. Google disagrees with me.

Edit

I flipped the first set of / to \ and now I'm back to

> Does ....\Project\folder\folder2\file.h
> specify a file name or directory name on the target (F = file, D =
> directory)?

Comment: ${project_loc} is the absolute path to the project, so it does not make sense to put `../` in front of it.

Comment: I removed the ../ before it, now I have "File not found"

Comment: xcopy \src\folder\file.h ..\..\OtherProject\Folder\Folder2\file.h /Y 
0 File(s) copied

Is what I have now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xcopy "${ProjDirPath}\src\folder\file.h" "..\..\OtherProject\folder\folder2\file.h" /Y
```

I had a typo somewhere in the destination, but I used ${ProjDirPath} as ${Project_loc} did not exist for the source.